# read webforms fields in a mobile app and write submissions to the site database

Tags: services

I have a courses site where students take online courses and then take exams and get their certificates.

The courses content type has an entity reference to "Lessons" content type which has a further reference to Exams content type ( Webform).

The progress of user is being stored in a custom table in database.

Now we need to build a native mobile app with login / registration, and taking courses and exams features. (user registration / login  and progress should be synced with site database)

Any ideas to start with? Custom API, web services or reading and writing to database directly.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

I believe services will fulfill your needs. You can try with  [Services](https://www.drupal.org/project/services) module.

You may require to customize the module for your custom made features in the site.

Comment: how about user login / registration features. Services will handle that aswell ?

Comment: yes It will. Refer this link for more details http://www.wdtutorials.com/2013/04/11/drupal-7-tutorial-web-services-basics#.VsSD4XV96kA

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend [DrupalGap](http://drupalgap.org) for this situation. With it, and a few contrib modules, you'll have an app that can display and submit Webforms. Here are the key players in this scenario:

- https://www.drupal.org/project/drupalgap (dependent on the [Services](https://www.drupal.org/project/services) module)
- http://drupalgap.org/project/webform

DrupalGap has built in support user login/logout/registration, and with the DrupalGap Webform module, it adds support for the display and submission of webforms in various application environments (mobile apps, web-apps, headless). The scenario you describe is attainable with probably 10 lines of custom code/terminal-commands or less.

Comment: can i install DrupalGap on top of my existing running website? Or i should have thought about DrupalGap when the website was being built.

Comment: On the Drupal side, DrupalGap is just a module so you can enable/disable/uninstall as needed. It's designed to work with brand new or pre-existing Drupal sites, and your app's source code remains separate from Drupal should you want to continue or abort mission.